# On the non-cyclic subgroups of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

Let $G=Q N_G(P)  $ be a finite non-nilpotent solvable group, where $N_G(P)=P \times (Q \cap N_G(P)) \times Q_8$ is a non-normal maximal subgroup of $G$ and $Q \cong C_q \times C_q \trianglelefteq G$, ($P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$ is cyclic, $Q \in {\rm Syl}_q(G); q \ne 2$, $Q_8 \trianglelefteq G$ and $Q \cap N_G(P) \cong C_q \trianglelefteq G $  ).

Clearly, $N_G(P)$ is a non-normal subgroup of $G$ which is non-cyclic. I want to find two non-conjugate non-normal subgroups($\ne N_G(P)$) of $G$ which are non-cyclic.

${\bf My \ try:}$ Since $PQ_8 <N_G(P)$, we get from Frattini argument $PQ_8 \ntrianglelefteq G$. Clearly, $PQ_8$ is non-cyclic and non-conjugate with $N_G(P)$.

Since $Q=[Q,P] \times C_Q(P)=[Q,P] \times (Q \cap N_G(P))$ and $[Q,P] \le G^{\prime} \nleq N_G(P)$, we have $[Q,P] = G^{\prime} \cong C_q$. So $p \mid q-1$, by First isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: Clearly $Q_8$ is non-cyclic and since $Q$ is elementary abelian of order $q^2$, it is non-cyclic too

Comment: you right, i edited it. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps writing down your group better would help. From what I can gather, $G$ has a normal subgroup $Q\times Q_8$, whose quotient has order $p$. If $x$ denotes an element of order $p$ in $G$, then $p$ centralizes $Q_8$, centralizes a subgroup of order $q$, and acts non-trivially on $Q$ itself. Thus $G\cong C_q\times Q_8\times H$, where $H$ is $C_q\rtimes C_p$.

Comment: From this, one sees that, if $P=\langle x\rangle$, $PQ_8C_q$ and $PQ_8$ cannot be normal (or cyclic).

Comment: if $PQ_1 \cong PC_q $ is normal in $G$, then by Frattini argument, $G=Q_1 N_G(P)$, So $Q=Q_1 \times (Q \cap N_G(P))$, which is true.

Comment: I'm not sure why you wrote that, or what it's supposed to prove, but any subgroup $PC_q$ is cyclic unless it's the subgroup $H$ I wrote down, and that one is normal.

Comment: Because $[Q ,N_G(P)] \ne 1$. If every subgroup $PC_q$ is cyclic, then $Q \le N_G(P)$, a contradiction.

Comment: "any subgroup $PC_q$ is cyclic unless it's the subgroup $H$". I've answered your question in the comment. Do you have a question about it? A doubt about it? A string of symbols means nothing unless you also add words saying what they purport to show. I have given two non-cyclic, non-normal subgroups. Do you disagree? Are you trying to prove that they are examples?

Comment: I said in my try $PQ_8 C_q=N_G(P)$ and $PQ_8$ are non-normal and non-cyclic.

Comment: Did you find another subgroup?

Comment: Yes, but then there were a string of symbols that I couldn't make head nor tail of. So I suggested to rewrite $G$ so that its structure is more transparent. At that point the normal and non-normal subgroups are clear. (There are exactly two non-normal, non-cyclic subgroups.)

Comment: Also, if you have found the two subgroups in the first paragraph, what is the second paragraph of symbols for?

Comment: because i want three subgroups

Comment: You literally wrote that you want two. Edit your post to make it clearer. For example, by writing what you are actually trying to prove, rather than something else.

Comment: Ok, edited. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group of the type described above. The Sylow $2$-subgroup $R$ is normal, and the Sylow $q$-subgroup $Q$ is normal. Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup. Then $R$ normalizes $P$ and $Q$, so $G\cong R\times PQ$. Thus $R$ is a direct factor of $G$. Notice that $Q$ has $q+1$ subgroups of order $q$. Let $Q_1=N_Q(P)$, and note that $Q_1\leq C_G(P)$. Thus $Q_1$ centralizes all of $G$, so $G\cong R\times Q_1\times H$ for some subgroup $H$ of order $qp$. Let $Q_2$ denote a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $H$. Thus
$$ G\cong R\times Q_1\times (Q_2\rtimes P).$$
Since $Q_2$ does not normalizes $P$, the action of $P$ on $Q_2$ is non-trivial.

Let $X$ be a subgroup of $G$, and first suppose that $X$ contains $Q_2$. Then $X/Q_2$ is a subgroup of $R\times Q_1\times P$, and all subgroups of this are normal. Thus all subgroups of $G$ containing $Q_2$ are normal.

Thus if $X$ is not normal then it cannot contain $Q_2$. Since every $2$-subgroup of $G$ is normal and a direct factor, we may write $X$ as $(X\cap R)\times (X\cap PQ)$. We see that $X$ is normal if and only if $X\cap PQ$ is normal, and $X$ is non-cyclic if and only if either $R\leq X$ or $X\cap PQ$ is non-cyclic.

Thus if $R\leq X$ then $X$ is always non-cyclic, and we just need to classify non-normal subgroups of $PQ$. Since the action of $P$ on $Q_2$ is non-trivial it is free, hence the action of $P$ on the subgroups of order $q$ in $Q$ must have exactly two fixed points, and $(q-1)/p$ distinct $p$-cycles. Thus there are exactly two normal subgroups of order $q$ in $G$, and $(q-1)$ non-normal ones. (Alternative proof: $Q$ is a $2$-dimensional $\mathbb F_q$-vector space, and hence a non-scalar element of order $p$ has at most two $1$-dimensional eigenspaces on it, $Q_1$ and $Q_2$.)

On the other hand, $P$ is not normal either, yielding another class. The only subgroups of order $pq$ are $Q_1P$ (not normal) and $Q_2P$ (normal), and of course $QP$ is normal.

Thus the non-normal (non-cyclic) subgroups of $G$ containing $R$ are, up to conjugacy:

1. $RP$, of order $8p$;
2. $RQ_1P$, of order $8qp$;
3. $(q-1)/p$ diagonal subgroups $R\bar Q$ of $RQ$ not equal to $RQ_i$, of order $8q$.

If, on the other hand, $R\not\leq X$, then we need a non-normal, non-cyclic subgroup of $PQ$. The only non-normal subgroups are all cyclic, and so the list above is complete.

Comment: (One also sees, from this description, that $G$ is unique up to isomorphism.)

Comment: I cant understand this: "hence the action of P on the subgroups of order q in Q must have exactly two fixed points, and (q−1)/p distinct p-cycles". can i ask you explain to me?

Comment: Well, it's either that or $P=\langle x\rangle$ normalizes more than two subgroups of order $q$ in $Q$. It normalizes $Q_1=\langle a\rangle$ and $Q_2=\langle b\rangle$, so suppose $P$ normalizes $Q_3=\langle ab^i\rangle$ for some $1\leq i\leq q-1$. But then $(ab^i)^x=a^xb^{ix}$ must be a power of $(ab^i)$. But $a^x$ is a power of $a$, and $b^x$ is a power of $b$. Thus $a^x$ is the same power of $a$ as $b^x$ is a power of $b$. So $P$ acts as a scalar on $Q$, but this is not true.

Comment: Thank you so much